# I am using the zklib library biiometric device to get records of attendance for the students but it showing me blank page

Tags: php, jquery, sockets

This is code and below is the IP address of the  device please help me out i tried this many times but i dont know why it is sending me bank page it is not getting any data  on this site atd.softghor.com it is working but when i use the code on my site it does not load any data i have used few lines of code becasue stackoverflow was not allowing me to use the fullcode

```
<?php
    include "zklib/zklib.php";

    $zk = new ZKLib("103.88.235.245", 4370);



    $ret = $zk->connect();
    print_r($ret);
    sleep(1);
    if ( $ret ): 
        $zk->disableDevice();
        sleep(1);
?>
```

Comment: Do you have display errors turned on in PHP?

Comment: yes errors are turn on
it just says blank page

Comment: And echoing some random text does anything? Try a var_dump on $ret instead

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem, try this:

```
$zk = new ZKLibrary('X.X.X.X', 4370);
$zk->connect();
$zk->disableDevice();
$users = $zk->getUser();
print_r($users);
$zk->enableDevice();
$zk->disconnect();
```

This will connect and print in array all the users.
$zk->connect, is the way you connect (method), you wont have a "response" to save in $ret.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the version of PHP because the library just support PHP 7.4 or lower, and you have to uncomment the socket in the php.ini